# Matching of debit and credit entries in Ms Excel or VBA

Tags: excel, vba

One specific problem that I am targeting today is matching of debit and credit amounts in an Excel sheet where we do not have a common criteria or lookup values. What we have is only numbers.

I tried to do it in a lot of ways but failed. If I have a `10` and a `-5,-3,-2` as a credit then I have to match it manually. Is there any way that the cells which are becoming zero automatically get highlighted? Are there any better ways to do it?

[image: Sample]

Comment: Please  illustrate your results desired by uplaoding an example case. Your sample is not self explanatory.

Comment: This was asked recently... Without a common identifier or even unique amounts then about the only thing you can do is use conditional formatting to highlight a zero...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is by using Solver

```
•   Put your data in A1:A12
•   In B13, put a formula =SUMPRODUCT(A1:A12,B1:B12)
•   Set up solver so that B1:12 must be binary (ie 1 or 0)
•   In B14 put a "target" score, 100 in your example
•   in B15 put =ABS(B13-B14)
•   Set solver to look for the minimum value in B15 (to either give you an exact solution with no difference, or closest solution with smallest possible difference)
In this case the simplest solution is setting 100 to "on" (ie 1), all other values es "off" (0)
Screenshot for xl2003 for solving for 367 below (as this is more complex than 100)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks ryguy72. This has worked. Thanks for making me learn a new thing.